# C, Арифметика с адресами памяти

Tags: c++, c, указатели, память, адрес

Вот код:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("pointer address: %p\n", &n);
    printf("pointer address + 1: %p\n", (&n+0x1));
    return 0;
}
```

Вот результат:

```
pointer address: 0061FF1C
pointer address + 1: 0061FF20
```

Почему при добавлении 1, получается значение, которое должно получится при добавлении 4?
С чем это связано?

Windows 10
GCC 6.3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В соответствии с типом указателя.

Чтобы `*(p+i)` было эквивалентно `p[i]`, в арифметике указателей смещение при сложении происходит на размер типа. В вашем случае - на размер `int`.

Answer (score 0):

вы добавляете целочисленное значение, int - может быть как 16 так и 32 и 64 разрядным в зависимости от его модификаторов длины. В стандартном варианте он 32 разрядный , то есть 32бита / 8 = 4 байта

Comment: `В стандартном варианте он 32 разрядный` Это где такое написано что `int` == 32 бита? Вы что-то путаете с `int32_t` и `int`.

Comment: Если не добавлять модификаторы short= = 16, long = =64, то int по стандарту является 32 разрядным

Comment: Не хотелось бы вас разочаровывать, но хотелось бы ссылку на стандарт... Я нашел 4.1.1.2. - "Certain aspects and operations of the abstract machine are described in this document as implementationdefined
(for example, sizeof(int))." Еще рекомендую посмотреть 6.7.1.1...