# СИ двумерные массивы

Tags: c, массивы

Как работает `scanf("%d", (a + i*m + j));`?
Если `a`-массив, то как мы можем к нему прибавить `im+j`

```
// Выделение памяти
      a = (int*)malloc(n*m * sizeof(int));
      // Ввод элементов массива
      for (i = 0; i<n; i++)  // цикл по строкам
      {
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)  // цикл по столбцам
        {
          printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
          scanf("%d", (a + i*m + j));
        }
      }
```

Comment: i*m + j-индекс как я понял,а a зачем

Comment: Просто почитайте арифметику указателей  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097364/c-Арифметика-с-адресами-памяти/1097366#1097366

Comment: `a + i*m + j == & ( a [  i*m + j ] )`

Comment: `a` — это не массив. Это указатель на первый элемент одномерного массива из `n*m` элементов типа `int`. К указателям можно прибавлять целые числа. Про смысл такой операции можете немного почитать в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248532). В вашем примере с одномерным массивом работают так, будто в нём хранится матрица из `n` строк и `m` столбцов.

Answer (score 1):

Двумерный массив

```
int a[M][N];
```

располагается в памяти одним блоком построчно. К элементу `a[i][j]` молжно обратиться и как к `&a[0][0]+i*N+j` - пропускаем `i` строк по `N` элементов и в строке обращаемся к `j`-му элементу.

То же можно сымитировать динамически, выделяя достаточную память (для `M*N` элементов) и обращаясь к `a+i*N+j`, потому что `a` и есть указатель на самый первый элемент.